# How to say someone's (possessive) home in Japanese?

Tags: translation, syntax, names, english-to-japanese, possession

The romantic phrase "you're my home," I was wondering how you would translate that into Japanese using someone's name? More specifically, how to say "Mya's home" & "Nathan's home" in Japanese, but less like a literal house and more like what is meant when people say they are "home," whether or not it is a country, state, or even with a person. *Note: I mean Mya's and Nathan's possessively, not Mya is/Nathan is.*
We were going with ネイサンズホーム and ミャスホーム but I was told that the word for home/house needed to be in hiragana not katagana and the syntax is wrong. However, I was never told the correct way to say it, so I am looking for extra guidance, thanks!

Comment: i think the best word for home in this context is ふるさと. technically it means hometown. but in literature or modern poetry or songs it’s used with much the same emotional impact/feel as when we speak of ‘home’ in english.

Comment: @A.Ellett Why not just put that in an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @kandyman good question: (1) technically because i didn’t actually answer the question. but if you can improve my comment, by all means go for it. (2) because the OP is asking for a translation which we generally don’t do here.